# Covert a string to UTF8 in php

Tags: php, utf-8

This is the content I have in DB

```
The gift is an expression of renewed commitment for ValentineÃ¢â<82>¬â<84>¢s Day
```

I want to convert it in regular format in PHP.I used **utf8_encode()**, it was not working for my string.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this.

Edited:

I got this problem when I run through terminal.

Comment: is the utf charset set, on the page where you output the string? `<meta charset='utf-8'> `

Comment: Can you give a hex dump of that data? Maybe it’s already UTF-8 encoded but you don’t properly tell the client it’s UTF-8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Maybe your terminal just misinterprets the data, which is already perfectly fine UTF-8.

Comment: @deceze yeah, that would be the proper way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql convert like this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(_latin1'Müller' USING utf8);
```

see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html) for more info